# How can i use paypal api for transfer money to bank account in php?

Tags: php, paypal

I have no any idea about it. I serched my sites but i can't find solutions.

My requirement is that, my query fetches bank account number from database,

For example, there r one record given by my query then i want to send money to this bank account.

what should i do??? Which api use for me??

My code is given below:

```
$queryOperator = "SELECT * FROM operatortransaction AS ot LEFT JOIN paymenttransaction AS pt ON
                    ot.OperatorID != pt.OperatorID WHERE ot.IsPaymentRequest = 1 AND ot.Amount != pt.Amount ";

$arrOperator = $obj->select($queryOperator);

$count = 0;

if(!empty($dataOperator))
{
    foreach($arrOperator as $operator)
    {
        if($arrOperator[$count]['Amount'] >= $arrOperator[$count]['RequestAmount'])
        {
            $queryDetail = "SELECT * FROM operatorprofile WHERE UserID = '$arrOperator[$count]['OperatorID']' ";
            $Data = $obj->select($queryDetail);


            // i want to put api code here......//

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your own bank account? If not, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try to use PayPal Xclick

```
<form action="https://secure.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal" id="paypal">
<!-- Pre Populate the Paypal Checkout Page With Customer Details, -->
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo Firstname?>">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo Lastname?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo Email?>">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php echo Address?>">
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<?php echo Address2?>">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo City?>">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo Postcode?>">
<input type="hidden" name="day_phone_a" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="day_phone_b" value="<?php echo Mobile?>">

<!-- We dont need to use _ext-enter anymore to prepopulate pages -->
<!-- cmd = _xclick will automatically pre populate pages -->                                                  
<!-- More Info: https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1332 -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@email.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to Your Business Name" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />

<!-- Allow customer to enter desired quantity -->
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Name of Item" />

<!-- Custom Value You want to send and process back in the IPN -->
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo session_id().?>" /> 

<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?php echo $shipping_price; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $invoice_id ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total_order_price; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/shop/paypal/thankyou"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/shop/paypal/cancelled" />

<!-- Where to send the paypal IPN to. -->
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/shop/paypal/process" />
```

NOTICE

Do remember to make a very strong VALIDATION!!!